# Time series plot showing with reversed axis

Tags: python, pandas, date, bokeh

I am new to Python and I am trying to build an interactive line plot using data frame with Pandas and Bokeh. Each time I run the code, the plot shows the wrong way round and the x-axis does not show the dates.

Please can someone help a new learner overcome this?

I am now using this updated code below but still having the same issue:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Span
df = pd.read_csv(
    "Pubdata.csv",
    engine='python',
    parse_dates=[1],
    date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y'),
    header=0
)
df.head()
p = figure(
    title="Number of Pubs",
    x_axis_type="datetime",
   
)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Number'

p.line(x=df.Date, y=df.Number, line_color="red", line_width = 3)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ('Date', '@x{%Y-%m-%d}'), # use ('date', '@x{%Y-%m-%d}') to show more than the year
        ('Number of Pubs', '@y')
    ],
    formatters = {"@x": "datetime"},
))
show(p)
```

At the moment I am not too worried about adding the hover tool until I have resolved the plotting issue.

The plot shows like this:

[image: Plot isnt showing the correct way, I am trying to plot number of pubs visited per date.]

Here is a sample of the data:

[image: Sample of data]

[image: Attempting to form a plot similar to this]

Here is a sample of data:

| Name | Date | Number | Drink |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The Fountain | 30/08/2019 | 1 | N/A |
| The Fox & Duck | 01/09/2019 | 2 | N/A |
| King William IV | 01/09/2019 | 3 | N/A |
| The Prince Albert | 01/09/2019 | 4 | N/A |
| Drayman's Son | 01/09/2019 | 5 | N/A |
| The Sussex Arms | 02/09/2019 | 6 | N/A |
| King Arthur's Arms Inn | 03/09/2019 | 7 | N/A |
| Old Mary's | 03/09/2019 | 8 | Estrella x2 |
| Mitre Lancaster Gate | 03/09/2019 | 9 | Kronenbourg |
| The Crown | 04/09/2019 | 10 | N/A |

I am trying to map going to 500 different pubs across 5 years.

Comment: what to you mean by "  the wrong way round and the x-axis does not show the dates.". Can you insert a print screen of result and a sample of data ?

Comment: Hey, I have added the plot and a sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on SO @bellablot.

Bokeh can parse `datetime` objects, if you set `x_axis_type` to `"datetime"`. The rest does bokeh for you.

To fulfill the requirements, you have to make sure your date information is parsed by [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv). You can use the parameter `parse_dates` and `infer_datetime_format`.

If your DataFrame has the correct form you can apply the steps below.

### Example

#### pandas

It is important to add the information about the datetime format to `pd.read_csv()`, because it is possible, that the detection mode sometimes fails.

In the code below, I used a regular expression to find all whitespaces with the length of 2 or more as a separator. This is because I copied your table. The separator is normally `,` or `;`. Please adapt it in your code. The StringIO section is just for demonstration. Repleace this with your path to your file.

The parsed DataFrame has the correct types and can be used in bokeh steight forward.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

text="""Name    Date    Number  Drink
The Fountain    30/08/2019  1   N/A
The Fox & Duck  01/09/2019  2   N/A
King William IV     01/09/2019  3   N/A
The Prince Albert   01/09/2019  4   N/A
Drayman's Son   01/09/2019  5   N/A
The Sussex Arms     02/09/2019  6   N/A
King Arthur's Arms Inn  03/09/2019  7   N/A
Old Mary's  03/09/2019  8   Estrella x2
Mitre Lancaster Gate    03/09/2019  9   Kronenbourg
The Crown   04/09/2019  10  N/A
"""

df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(text),
    sep=r'\s{2,}', # use regular expression | \s is any kind of whitespace
    engine='python',
    parse_dates=[1],
    date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y'),
    header=0
)
```

#### bokeh

Here I import HoverTool and Span as extra models. With Span it is possible to draw vertical or horizontal lines with no end.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Span
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Number':list(range(10)),
    'Date': pd.date_range('2022-12-22', periods=10, freq='D')
})


p = figure(
    title="Number of Pubs",
    x_axis_type="datetime",
    plot_height = 350,
    plot_width = 350
)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Number'

p.line(x=df.Date, y=df.Number, line_color="red", line_width = 3)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ('year', '@x{%Y}'), # use ('date', '@x{%Y-%m-%d}') to show more than the year
        ('Number of crimes', '@y')
    ],
    formatters = {"@x": "datetime"},
))

# horizontal line
hspan = Span(location=4, dimension='width', line_color='#bbbbbb', line_width=2)
p.add_layout(hspan)

# vertical line line
# vspan = Span(location=df.Date[0]+pd.Timedelta(365*2.5, 'D'), dimension='height', line_color='#bbbbbb', line_width=2)
# p.add_layout(vspan)

show(p)
```

### Output

[image: line plot over time]

### Comment

This solution adds one Hovertool with one formatter to show only the year. There are many more options and you can read about it [`HoverTool.formatters`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.HoverTool.formatters) and [DatetimeTickFormatter](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.DatetimeTickFormatter) in the bokeh documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have attached an image of the plot line I am trying to achieve. Your solution has solved the date axis problem but I am now unable to plot my data? Would you be able to help further please?

Comment: You didn't mention the error you have? At the moment I can't work with your data, because it is an image. Please add the first 10 lines of your csv (no image) to your question. Then I can adapt my answer.

Comment: Hey, thank you four responding. I have added the data. I am trying to map reaching 500 pubs in 5 years and then plot the number of pubs I have actually gone on the dates I visited them.

Comment: I updated my answer and hope that you can adapt your code to get the figure.

Comment: Thank you for the update - I am unfortunately having the same original issue now. I will post the code I am using.  Sorry to keep bothering you, could you possibly have a look again? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please check your column names? Use `print(df.columns)`. Maybe there are whitespaces. This is an usual mistake. If there are whitespaces, you can rename the columns using `df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns] `.